# Selector is:visible doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Solved:** This is a very very custom searchable dropdown I made. It actually works well now but I still have a little problem. Can I make it so when I use arrow up/down, the highlighted item can still be seen on the dropdown like a usual dropdown (the dropdown get scrolled by itself along with up/down key and not get hidden)? As you can see I tried using `$(".selectable-dropdown").scrollTop(34);` when the dropdown need scrolling but it seems like it only work once.

And also, I put this line `if(!$(".selectable-selected").is(":visible"))` on the search function. What I want to achieve is when I search something and also already selected something from the list, if the selected `li` not included in search result, the topmost of search result get highlighted. But it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Any help appreciated! :)

**Edit:** I finally know how to make it works! The scrolling amount has to be growing and added everytime I click the up/down key. The 2nd question still unsolved though.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").on("keyup", function (e) {
    $(".selectable-dropdown").show();
    if(e.keyCode != 37 && e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 39 && e.keyCode != 40 && e.keyCode != 13) {
      if(!$(".selectable-selected").is(":visible")) {
        $(".selectable-dropdown li:first-child").addClass("selectable-hover");   
      }
      var query = this.value;
      $(".selectable-dropdown-each").each(function (i, elem) {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
          $(this).show();
        } 
        else {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

function repositionSelectable() {
  var selectablePosition = $(".form-dropdown").offset();
  var selectableWidth = $(".form-dropdown").width();
  var selectablePositionLeft = selectablePosition.left;
  var selectablePositionTop = selectablePosition.top + 56;
  $(".selectable-dropdown-wrapper").css({"top": selectablePositionTop + "px"});
  $(".selectable-dropdown-wrapper").css({"left": selectablePositionLeft + "px"});
  $(".selectable-dropdown-wrapper").css({"width": selectableWidth + "px"});
}

$("#selectable").focus(function() {
  repositionSelectable();
  $(".selectable-dropdown").show();
  if (!$(".selectable-selected").length)  {
    $(".selectable-dropdown li:first-child").addClass("selectable-hover");
  }
});

$(".selectable-dropdown-each").click(function() {
  var selectedChoice = $(this).text();
  $("#selectable").val(selectedChoice);
  $(".selectable-dropdown-each").removeClass("selectable-selected");
  $(this).addClass("selectable-selected");
  $(".selectable-dropdown").hide();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  repositionSelectable();
});

$(".selectable-dropdown-each").mouseover(function() {
  $(".selectable-dropdown li").removeClass("selectable-hover");
  $(this).addClass("selectable-hover");
});

$(".selectable-dropdown-each").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("selectable-hover");
});

var needScrollTop = false;
var scrollAmount = 0;

$("#selectable").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
    if (!$(".selectable-selected").length)  {
      if (!$(".selectable-hover").length)  {
        $(".selectable-dropdown li:first-child").addClass("selectable-hover");
      }
      else {
        $(".selectable-hover").addClass("temp");
      }
    }
    else {
      if (!$(".selectable-hover").length)  {
        $(".selectable-selected").addClass("temp");
      }
      else {
        $(".selectable-hover").addClass("temp");
      }
    }
    if($(".temp").next().hasClass("selectable-dropdown-each")) {
      $(".temp").next().addClass("selectable-hover");
      $(".temp").removeClass("selectable-hover temp");
    }
    else {
      
    }
    var highlightPosition = $(".selectable-hover").offset();
    var selectablePositionTest = $(".selectable-dropdown").offset();
    if (needScrollTop) {
      $(".selectable-dropdown").scrollTop(scrollAmount + 34);
      scrollAmount += 37;
      console.log("scroll");
    }
    if(((highlightPosition.top + 36) >= (selectablePositionTest.top + 200)) && !needScrollTop) {
      $(".selectable-dropdown").scrollTop(16);
      needScrollTop = true;
      scrollAmount += 16;
    }
  }
  else {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up 
      if ($(".selectable-hover").length) {
        $(".selectable-hover").addClass("temp");
      }
      else {
        $(".selectable-selected").addClass("temp");
      }
      if($(".temp").prev().hasClass("selectable-dropdown-each")) {
        $(".temp").prev().addClass("selectable-hover");
        $(".temp").removeClass("selectable-hover temp");
      }
    }
    else {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter  
        var selectedChoice = $(".selectable-hover").text();
        $("#selectable").val(selectedChoice);
        $(".selectable-dropdown-each").removeClass("selectable-selected");
        $(".selectable-hover").addClass("selectable-selected");
        $(".selectable-dropdown-each").removeClass("selectable-hover");
        $(".selectable-dropdown").hide();
        $("#selectable").blur();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 768px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #0099ff;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.input-text {
  height: 34px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  width: 366px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 0 0 12px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.input-text:focus {
  border: solid 1px #00c983; 
}

::placeholder {
  color: #c4c4c4; 
  font-size: 13px;
}

.form-input-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

.input-disabled {
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.form-unit {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.input-select-btn {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.on-disabled-btn {
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-select-btn i {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
}

.form-row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.form-divided {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-divided-left {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.datepicker-calendar {
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-icon {
  transform: translateY(-2px); 
}

.selectable-dropdown {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15) !important;
  border: none !important;
  margin-top: 4px !important;
}

.selectable-dropdown-wrapper {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.selectable-dropdown {
  max-height: 200px; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#selectable {
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.selectable-selected {
  background-color: #eee; 
}

.selectable-dropdown-each {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  padding-left: 8px !important;
}

.selectable-dropdown-each {
  display: block; 
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px !important;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.selectable-hover {
  background-color: #CAF1FF;
}

.form-dropdown {
  margin-bottom: 24px; 
}

.labeled-row {
  display: block;
  width: 366px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.labeled-label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 96px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.labeled-input {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 115px);
}

.labeled-input .input-text {
  width: 100%; 
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.labeled-input a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
  color: #333;
}

.labeled-input a:hover,
.labeled-input a:focus,
.labeled-input a:active {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
  width: 366px !important;
}

.datepicker {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .form {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided-left {
    margin-right: 24px;
  }
  
  .form-divided {
    width: calc(50% - 14px);
  }
  
  .input-text,
  textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .input-select-btn {
    right: 0;
  }
  
  .labeled-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .form {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .form-divided-left {
    margin-right: 0; 
  }
  
  .input-text,
  textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .labeled-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-unit form-divided form-divided-left">
      <label for="date" class="form-input-label">Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-text input-datepicker" id="date" placeholder="Select date">
      <a class="input-select-btn" id="datepicker-btn"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="form-unit form-divided form-dropdown">
      <label for="selectable" class="form-input-label">Type</label>
      <input id="selectable" class="input-text" type="text" placeholder="Select type">
      <a class="input-select-btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-down dropdown-icon"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="selectable-dropdown-wrapper">
  <ul class="selectable-dropdown">
     <li class="selectable-dropdown-each">Choice ABC</li>
     <li class="selectable-dropdown-each">Choice BCD</li>
     <li class="selectable-dropdown-each">Choice DEF</li>
     <li class="selectable-dropdown-each">Choice GHI</li>
     <li class="selectable-dropdown-each">Choice IJK</li>
     <li class="selectable-dropdown-each">Choice UVW</li>
     <li class="selectable-dropdown-each">Choice XYZ</li>
     <li class="selectable-dropdown-each">Choice 123</li>
     <li class="selectable-dropdown-each">Choice 345</li>
     <li class="selectable-dropdown-each">Choice 789</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```